# Doing a refund on paypal using NVP/SOAP using powershell

Tags: powershell, soap, paypal

I'm trying to perform a refund on Paypal developer account but I keep getting errors while trying to run this command via powershell:

```
$certpath="E:\AAAA\cert_key.pem"
curl -v -E $certpath -F content=C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\res.xml;type=text/xml" https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/
```

The Content of the XML are as below which i took from paypal developer site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Username>username</Username>
<Password>password</Password>
<Subject/>
</Credentials>
</RequesterCredentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<RefundTransactionReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
<RefundTransactionRequest xsi:type="ns:RefundTransactionRequestType">
<Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0</Version>
<TransactionID xsi:type="ebl:TransactionId">3P573784GG4876055</TransactionID>
<RefundType>Full</RefundType>
<Memo>Shell script FULL refund example</Memo>
</RefundTransactionRequest>
</RefundTransactionReq>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But i keep getting below error:

```
curl : * timeout on name lookup is not supported
At line:2 char:1
+ curl -v -E $certpath -F "content=C:\Users\MICHELANGELO\Desktop\res.xml;type=text ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (* timeout on na...s not supported:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

*   Trying 173.0.82.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 173 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 173 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4071 length 4096
* schannel: a client certificate has been requested
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4071 length 5095
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 365 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 91 length 5095
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (step 3/3)
> POST /2.0/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 203
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------f4cd70d3c58d2816
> 
0   203    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
* Done waiting for 100-continue
} [203 bytes data]
* schannel: client wants to read 16384 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 17408
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: Curl_read_plain returned CURLE_RECV_ERROR
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 4096
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
100   203    0     0  100   203      0     92  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    92
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to send close msg: Failed sending data to the peer (bytes written: -1)
* schannel: clear security context handle
curl: (56) Send failure: Connection was reset
```

Any help would be really appreciated.